# Is there a "How to answer" help page?

Tags: support, answers

In other *Stack Exchange* sites there's a help page on how to answer (such as [this one at *Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)).

I can't find a page like this here, at *Seasoned Advice*. I find it would be useful for many newcomers, and expert users can link it as comments in newbies answers that need to be improved.

Comment: Isn't most of that covered in the FAQ? I accept the FAQ is brief (and could be expanded) but guidance is there for asking and answering questions.

Comment: Actually, the so-called FAQ is mostly template from SO in general, and very unhelpful in my opinion.  For example, I was directed to read the FAQ on a question regarding some cultural taboo issues, but that isn't in the FAQ, its buried here on Meta which only experts will ever see or find.  A true FAQ would be much more accessible and and depth, or at least linked to the deeper information.

Comment: I often search in the FAQ and find it's too short. But it's also true that a larger one might get people not reading it.

Comment: While it exists, I had never seen it before, and I guess I must have clicked every link around the site at least once, so it can't be easy to find by the people who need it. How did you find the one on SO?

Comment: @rumtscho I think I first saw it at a link at [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/456/should-we-have-a-standard-comment-to-new-users). When I wrote this question googled it for Stack Overflow. My searches for it at Seasoned Advice were not good (as right now I've googled and found it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Stack Exchange site has it at the same relative URL:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer